# UIImageView added to an NSArray doesn't respond

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am fairly new to Objective-C, this is the first time I really don't know what to do.

I have a class - `Parser` - which creates `UIImageViews`, `init`s them with images and adds them to the `UIView`. **The class also adds these `UIImageViews` to `NSMutableArray` - `imgArray`, which is a property of another class - `Page`.**

Then, on the click of a button, I call the `Page` class from a `Manager` class, loop through the `imgArray` and try to set a new images for the `UIImageViews` in the array.

It doesn't work. Actually nothing I do to the `UIImageViews` doesn't work.
I try `[img removeFromSuperView]`, `[img setHidden:YES]` and more. It doesn't response.

Here I declare the Array property in Page:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imgArray;
```

Here is the code from Parser where I create the image and add it to the array:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
        NSString *name = [c imageSource];
        [img setImage: [UIImage imageFromBook: name]];
        [view addSubview: img];
        [c setImage:img];
        if (!page.imgArray)
        {
            page.imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [page.imgArray addObject:img];
        [img release];
```

Here is the loop code from the Manager:

```
- (void) set3D:(bool)is3D
{
    Page *page = [[DataManager data] currentPage];
    int count = [page.imgArray count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *img = [page.imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image3DSource]];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How about that:
`
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"]];
    }`

Comment: @pKoul I need a reference to the already existing UIImageView in order to change it...

Comment: please provide us with some code where your imageviews and your array is initialized

Comment: Look at the obvious, make sure that the count > 0, and the frame is visible. Also add a line like: "UIImage* thePicture = [UIImage imageFromBook: name];" and verify that is returning a valid, non-NULL UIImage*

Comment: Also, try creating a subclass of UIImageVIew and draw a frame, or fill it with a solid color to make sure it is visible.

Comment: The original images are showing, only the loading or changing the images from the Array doesn't work. Also, I would like to say that when I added NSLog to the Loop function, to print the UIImageViews in the array, it printed all of the UIImageViews, no null values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store the UIImageView's in an array.

When the UIImageView's are created, you can tag them with an arbitrary number, like.

```
#define K_MIN_IMGV 100
#define K_MAX_IMGV 120

- (void) setupViews
{
    for (NSInteger count = K_MIN_IMGV; count < K_MAX_IMGV; ++count)
    {
        UIImageView *imgV = // create image view, set properties
        imgV.tag = count;   // tag the views for easy retrieval later
        ...
        [mainView addSubview: imgV]; // add subviews
        [imgV release], imgV = nil;  // mainView now manages, release our allocation
    }
}
```

// how to set new images

```
- (void) setupNewImages
{
    for (NSInteger count = K_MIN_IMGV; count < K_MAX_IMGV; ++count)
    {
        UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView *) [mainView viewWithTag: count]; // retrieve imageView
        [imgV setImage: newImage]; // set new image
    }
}
```

// To remove the imageView,  you can use

```
UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView *) [mainView viewWithTag: 123];
[imgV removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enumerate through the array using:

```
for(UIImageView* imageView in page.imgArray)
{
 //Do code
}
```

This will tell you if there any imageViews in page.imgArray.

How are you adding objects to NSMutableArray and how are you initialising your NSMutableArray.
I remember having a problem adding objects to NSMutableArray but setting my init to solved this:

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Also what properties have you set on imgArray in page? Are you retaining the values?

Need to see more code to gain a fuller understanding.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried to enumerate with "for in" and it didn't help. I don't know what more code should I post, but I will post as much as I can now in my question.

Comment: Can you put up your init for the page class?

Comment: I don't know exactly where the is the init for the Page class... I am actually working on a code which is part of an existing complex code that I got.

Comment: Have you created an instance of Page in your code? It seems strange you should be initialising a different class' property inside another class. If you jump to definition of 'page' you should be able to find a method with init somewhere and see how they're creating .

Comment: Here is the init function of the page but it doesn't really help: - (id)init {
 if(self = [super init]) {
  self.signFile = nil;
  self.pageID = nil;
  self.pageName = nil;
  self.musicFile = nil;
  self.bgImageFile = nil;
        self.bg3DImageFile = nil;
  flipable = NO;
  self.narrationFile = nil;
  self.firstContent = nil;
 }
 return self;
}

Comment: You're right that really doesn't help lol. Did you manage to find where they initialising imgArray in the code?

Comment: Also, I would like to say that when I added NSLog to the Loop function, to print the UIImageViews in the array, it printed all of the UIImageViews, no null values.

Comment: Did you mean to write UIImage imageFromBook? Have you created a category with a new method for initialising UIImage? Also is your frame legal?

Comment: the imgArray is initialized in the Parser class - I have pasted it in the question.

Comment: Yes, imageFromBook is some kind of customized method that returns UIImage.

Comment: If the NSLog is printing the UIImageViews but they don't response, what does it mean? It seems like they are not referenced to the original UIImageViews that appear on the screen...